# DRIVER POWER STATE FAILURE with a new Toshiba Satellite Laptop?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, graphics-card, toshiba-laptop

I just got my new Windows 10 Laptop from Toshiba. It is 15 inches, has an i76700HQ processor quad core, 4k screen, 16 GB Ram, 512 GB SSD and a 4GB NVidia 950 GTX Card.

Literally since I got it 5 days ago(online from Costco), every 30 minutes or so(sometimes longer or shorter) no matter what I am doing the Blue Screen of Death appears and restarts the computer using the "Driver Power State Failure" error.

I have done a lot of research on how to try to fix this- I updated all my drivers using DriverEasy. Before that I went into Safe Mode and entered devmgmt.msc in the run dialog box and got a list of all the drivers. 2 of them had a yellow exclamation point under them- firmware and general pnp monitor. I uninstalled them and then got the up to date drivers. Anyways, I went back and checked and they still are yellow in safe mode. I tried again to get the newest drivers but it says it is up to date!!! This is so frustrating!!! There are yellow exclamations by them in safe mode indicating the drivers need updated but when I try to update them they say they are up to date lol(pnp monitor driver says up to date but it is from 2006). What a joke.

Anyways, the Driver power State Failure error still comes like clockwork and I have to restart my whole computer. The safe mode driver thing didn't help at all.

I bought reimage and used it(firmware yellow exclamation point went away) and it seemed to have fixed some other stuff ironically but not that. I think there are some issues with the nvidia thing as I have read. I learned how to open dmp files and will attach a couple of them in this help question. Reading them there might be some issue with the pci too. I also analyzed that this was a Windows 8.1 laptop that was upgraded. I know that because in 1 of the dmps I was reading it said                                                               DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT   BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

Anyways, then I reinstalled windows through the reset option and it still did the BSOD Driver Power State Failure today but just once. I was also noticing that if I tried to open Chrome with the NVidia card Chrome would stop responding and soon after the BSOD would appear. Recently I disabled the NVidia Streaming Service and that really hasn't happened. Also I was noticing that if I didn't touch my computer for like 7-9 minutes the BSOD would appear. Just weird and frustrating.

Obviously whoever upgraded this laptop before selling it did a bad job because there are definitely some incompatibility there. I just would like to pinpoint it exactly and to know what to do after. I have spent way too much time on this when I should have been enjoying a nice laptop!! I hope there can be someone on here who can read my dump files, understand them and help me fix this. I have never had a windows 10 laptop before and I am a complete novice.

Lost my other dump files on my pc but I have a couple of them that I sent to me in an email that I cut and pasted. If anyone needs to see it please let me know.

[Recent Dump file](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=FE6261FD1C94B3C8%21473&cid=FE6261FD1C94B3C8)

Comment: Have you tried to do a pen drive system (linux maybe, or a [bootable maintenance one](http://www.pcworld.com/article/234779/the_bootable_maintenance_flash_drive.html)) to start the laptop with this system and to see if it arrives a kernel panic (BSOD) or if you have any hardware error recognized?

Comment: No I have not. Looks pretty complicated to do and if I have to do all that I might as well return the darn thing. I just want to understand the dmp file and what to do next.

Comment: the link to the dump is not working. Make sure you created the share link correctly.

Comment: You know to keep it real, I had a lot of trouble trying to zip it and send it. I am pretty clueless on this stuff. Could you quickly walk me through how to do it?? Or do you have an email and I could send you an email with a link?? Whatever is better for you.  Sorry for the bad link. I tried it on my computer and it seemed to work.

Comment: on https://onedrive.live.com/ select the dmp file, click on "share" button and "create link"